# Use a form to run queries on a date range

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007

I have an MS-Access DB that pulls information in from an Excel file with 6 worksheets, so I get 6 tables. I created 7 queries, all of which make tables from the excel data, 6 of those 7 do a count of an item ie:

```
SELECT DISTINCT DISPLAYNAME, COUNT(DISPLAYNAME)
FROM [TXFR REC]
GROUP BY DISPLAYNAME
```

The 7th query pulls those 6 tables together into a sort of report table by using left joins onto one of the tables, where the connection to all the others is a DISPLAYNAME.

I have created a `Form` with 4 buttons and two date boxes, a start date and an end date. What I want to do is the following:

1. Choose Start Date
2. Choose End Date
3. Press Button that runs the 7 queries in the order I specified by invoking the date range from steps 1 and 2 ** THIS IS WHERE I AM STUCK: I do not know how to force this date range on the queries **
4. Run the report
5. Export the report
6. Close the form

The date boxes are set to General Date and the method used for them is GetDates so you just click in the box and the calendar pops up and you choose your date.

I did see this post here but am not following to well:
[Date Range Form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1228530/displaying-totals-within-a-specified-date-range-in-microsoft-access)

Here is the text from a test query as suggested by a user and in the format suggested by the answering person:

```
SELECT [NO ADMITTING DX (HEALTH ISSUE)].PHYSICIANDISPLAYNAME, Count([NO ADMITTING DX (HEALTH ISSUE)].PHYSICIANDISPLAYNAME) AS CountOfPHYSICIANDISPLAYNAME INTO NO_ADMIT_DX_COUNT
FROM [NO ADMITTING DX (HEALTH ISSUE)]
WHERE ((([NO ADMITTING DX (HEALTH ISSUE)].PHYSICIANDISPLAYNAME) Is Not Null) And (([NO ADMITTING DX (HEALTH ISSUE)].AdmitDtm) Between Forms!PRINT_REPORT![START DATE] And FORMS!PRINT_REPORT![END DATE]))
GROUP BY [NO ADMITTING DX (HEALTH ISSUE)].PHYSICIANDISPLAYNAME;
```

** This query now works properly **

Thank you for all the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your query, use something like this.

```
   SELECT  DISPLAYNAME, COUNT(DISPLAYNAME)
 FROM [TXFR REC] 
  WHERE [TXFR REC].yourDate BETWEEN [Forms]![yourFormName]![yourStartDate] 
      AND [Forms]![yourFormName]![yourEndDateField]
GROUP BY DISPLAYNAME
```

All of your queries that you want to rely on a date range should have these parameters. The advantage to doing it this way is that you can give your two date fields on your form a datePicker. It would still work the same if you did something like this:

```
    SELECT  DISPLAYNAME, COUNT(DISPLAYNAME)
 FROM [TXFR REC] 
  WHERE [TXFR REC].yourDate BETWEEN [Please Enter a Start Date]
      AND [Please Enter an Ending Date]
GROUP BY DISPLAYNAME
```

It's all preference though. Just throw a button on there and go to Misc in the wizard and choose `run query` if you want.

Answer (score 1):

Edit your queries to rely on the value of the form in the where clause:

`[Forms]![`*form's name*`]![`*form's control*`]`

Here's a [Screenshot example](http://www.techonthenet.com/access/queries/filter1.php)

This will make your queries only work with the form, however.  You might consider copying your queries and renaming and editing the copies to reflect its limitation.

Comment: Above, [form value] needs to be the name of the control in your form, and you also need to have the form open with values populated in the date fields or you will get no results. If you want to run the queries with the form closed, another option would be to bind the date fields to a table and query based on the table field values.

Comment: Hi and thank you for the feed back. I want a button on the Form (Modal Dialogue) to run the queries, this will be a UI for people to just click the mouse a couple of times and get the info. I tried a test query and so far I get a black return table...still thinking it through.

Comment: @MCP_infiltrator can you add your test query to your question?  A screen shot of the query designer or the text of your SQL statement should suffice.

Comment: @coge.soft sure thing
I am actually going to do the query now and try to work through this so I'll show you what I have right now.